# Error while using filter in flutter for Listview

Tags: json, flutter, dart, filter, flutter-listview

I am trying to filter the list with element `data_code` which is received by a Stateful widget, but I am getting the error as below description

Code

```
 List list4=   list2.where(widget.bomdatareceived[0]['data_items'][0]['data_code'].contains(widget.data_code));
```

ERROR

```
type 'bool' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => bool'
```

JSON Data

```
"data_items": [
                                {
                 
                                    "data_code": "61",
                                    "data_name": "dat1",
                                    "data_item": "327",
                                },
                                {
                 
                                    "data_code": "61",
                                    "data_name": "dat4",
                                    "data_item": "390",

                                },
                                {
                 
                                    "data_code": "65",
                                    "data_name": "dat3",
                                    "data_item": "1056",
                                }
                            ]
```

The above JSON data is on the list, I want to implement a filter kind of thing in this ListView.builder, to enlist only those elements which have same `data_code`, I am not implementing any search bar kind of thing on the screen. I am receiving the value of `data_code`  from the previous screen and want to build the list which has the same `data_code` .

Please guide me how to resolve this issue. I am new at the learning of flutter

Comment: A similar type of question has been asked : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63879498/error-while-implementing-where-clause-on-the-list-from-json-in-flutter

Comment: @AdithyaShetty yeah , both the questions are similar , but none has the answer yet, can you please help with the answer, I will be very grateful to you for this

Comment: According to me, you are not using the where expression correctly, pls refer the docs

Comment: @AdithyaShetty as per your guidance , I have checked this link https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/where.html , please guide me with accurate implementation

Answer (score 1):

In `where` method you need to use function which returns bool and its argument is each element of a list. So in your situation it should be something similar to:

```dart
 var list4 = list2.where((item) => item.contains(widget.data_code));
```

I don't know how `list2` looks like, so it's sample condition.

Comment: Hi, I tried your answer  but it is giving me this error `type 'WhereIterable<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'` , do I need to provide some more details?

Comment: And `toList()` at the end